# Find rate of change of the $y$-coordinate with respect to time $\frac{dy}{dt}$

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble solving this Calculus problem and wondering if I could get some help.

"A particle is traveling around a circle whose equation is  $x^2 + y^2 = 25$ in such a way that the rate of change of its $x$-coordinate with respect to time, $\frac{dx}{dt}$, $= 2$. Find the rate of change of the $y$-coordinate with respect to time, $\frac{dy}{dt}$, when the particle is at the point $(3, -4)$ on the circle."

Comment: You have that $x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 =25$. What do you obtain by taking the derivate with respect to $t$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiate the given equation w.r.t to $t$ so we get $2x.dx/dt+2y.dy/dt=0$ now $x=3,y=-4 , dx/dt=2$ so substituting values we get $dy/dt=3/2$ . Hope this helps you.